# WSO2 User Engagement Server is multi-tenant and support virtual microsites

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant

Does WSO2 User Engagement Server (UES) server support multi-tenancy and each tenant can have their own space, microsites to be accessed, managed etc. Something like virtual portal in JBoss Gatein and/or WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported but we plan to have multi-tenancy support for UES in the next release of the product and it is already in our roadmap.